# Duplicating PHPs function isset

Tags: php, isset

I've been using a custom `__isset()` function already for a long time, which basically only exists to make the code look better and saves time typing:

```
function __isset(&$aVariable, $aDefault = null) {
    return isset($aVariable) ? $aVariable : $aDefault;
}
```

But today I found out that this function is actually creating the variable if it doesn't exist! And this is a huge problem when you are checking for array properties:

```
$lArray = ('A', 'B', 'C');
$lValue = __isset($lArray[4], 'D');
print_r($lArray); // Outputs 0=>'A', 1=>'B', 2=>'C', 3=>NULL
```

So what I want is to duplicate the current `isset()` function from PHP and change it to do what I want. The problem is that I cannot find the actual `isset()` function in the PHP source code...

A lot of frameworks are using an `isset()` function like I showed in first example, and I cannot image that I'm the first one who bump into this problem.

So my questions are:

1. Where can I find the actual `isset()` PHP function?
2. Where can I find the actual `isset()` C function (the real implementation)?
3. How to change the code so that it returns the value, or the specified default value?

Comment: Why. Just, why? At a guess a value is set because you're passing a reference, not a value.

Comment: Just BTW, Creating an alternative `isset()` function won't prevent php from throwing warnings for unset variables/indexes

Comment: If the isset function in C can accept non-existant variables, so can a duplicate of the function in C. That is the whole reason why I want to duplicate the isset function in the core.

Answer (score 3):

Why all this? Remove `&` and thats it:

```
function __isset($aVariable, $aDefault = null) {
    return isset($aVariable) ? $aVariable : $aDefault;
}
```

Comment: if you remove `&` you would get `Notice: Undefined offset` error

Comment: I'd say the warnings are a separate issue.

Comment: We are programming in a way that there will be no notices, warnings or errors at all. So this is not an option. We also do not suppress error messages with @ since this leads to undesired results in some cases.

Comment: @Raymond Ok, no notices, no @. So you are going to modify language core and recompile it and make all your scripts not-compatible with normal PHP. Funny.

Comment: @Petr I find it funny you say it that way... In which way is a custom PHP compilation, or an added PHP extension or an added Apache extension not-compatible with normal PHP? You are just adding functions, which extensions are invented for!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the array key exist before the actual comparison using [array_key_exist](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
$lArray = array('A','B','C');
$LValue = array_key_exists(2, $lArray)?$lArray[2]:'D';
echo $LValue;
```

sure you have to modify __isset to special handle arrays

Comment: The reason people are using the function as I described above is that the don't want to write such code for readability, otherwise I could also have done: $lValue = isset($lArray[4]) ? $lArray[4] : 'D';

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `&` sign `alone` would generate `Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in` What i think you should do is remove the `&` and suppress any `E_NOTICE error` with `@` ;

```
$lArray = array('A', 'B', 'C');
$lValue = __isset(@$lArray[4], 'D'); // or @__isset($lArray[4], 'D');

var_dump($lValue);
var_dump($lArray);

function __isset($aVariable, $aDefault = null) {
    return isset($aVariable) ? $aVariable : $aDefault ;
}
```

Output (with no E_NOTICE error)

```
string 'D' (length=1)
array
  0 => string 'A' (length=1)
  1 => string 'B' (length=1)
  2 => string 'C' (length=1)
```

Another solution is use another `isset` to manager array and object

```
$lArray = array('A','B','C');
$lValue = __issetComplex($lArray, 4, 'D');

var_dump($lValue);
var_dump($lArray);


function __issetComplex($mixed, $key, $aDefault = null) {
    if (is_array($mixed))
        return array_key_exists($key, $mixed) ? $mixed[$key] : $aDefault;
    if (is_object($mixed))
        return isset($mixed->key) ? $mixed->key : $aDefault;
    return $aDefault;
}
```

Lastly you can just override PHP isset function on your own  see [override_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php)

Comment: The problem is, you have to place `@` in all function calls - not the function itself.

Comment: We are programming in a way that there will be no notices, warnings or errors at all. So this is not an option. We also do not suppress error messages with @ since this leads to undesired results in some cases.

Comment: Also overriding the isset function is not what we want... isset returns boolean, we want to return the value or a default one. And since the isset function is the only function in PHP that does allow non-existant variables to be passed, this is an exceptional function. That's why we want to duplicate it in C.